# What is the best way to create an array of JSON objects from JSON stored in multiple rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Let's say that I have multiple rows in a table with an `nvarchar` column that contains JSON data. Each row would have some simple JSON object, like `{ "key": "value" }`. What is the best way to compose all of these objects into a single JSON object as an array, for a group of rows, such as:

```
{
   "data": [
       { "key": "value" },
       { "key": "value" },
       { "key": "value" }
   ]
}
```

There could be any number of groups, and any number of rows per group. Each object could be different.

Currently, my approach would be to use `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate them into a single string, but this is prone to odd text (e.g. `&#x0D;`) getting in there which makes it less than a resilient approach. It seems possible that I could use `JSON_MODIFY` but I'm not sure how I would use it in a way that accommodates unknown rows per group.

Comment: Why `FOR XML PATH` when `STRING_AGG` is available? `STRING_AGG([column], ',')` should concatenate correctly without further escaping issues (but test that, I'm not entirely sure :-)). Wrap with `CONCAT('{"data":[', ..., ']}')` and Bob, as they say, should be your uncle.

Comment: I incorrectly tagged this question with `sql-server-2017`, my apologies! Our environments are still on 2016 and so I can't leverage `STRING_AGG` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Creating arrays of JSON data in SQL is not exactly straightforward. Take the following table as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (id INT, jsonCol NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #test
    (
        id
        ,jsonCol
    )
VALUES
    (
        1
        ,N'{ "make": "ford" }'
    ),
    (
        1
        ,N'{ "make": "mazda" }'
    )
    ,
    (
        2
        ,N'{ "color": "black" }'
    )
```

You can use the following query to create a single JSON object with the array as you posted in your question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [data] = 
JSON_QUERY( '[' + STUFF(
                        (SELECT ',' + jsonCol FROM #test FOR XML PATH (''))
                        , 1, 1, '') 
            + ']') 
FROM #test 
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

The output would look like this:

```
{
    "data":[
            { "make": "ford" },
            { "make": "mazda" },
            { "color": "black" }
    ]
}
```

You can also correlate the id columns in the main and subqueries to get the json grouped by id.
Here's an example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
        , [json] = (SELECT DISTINCT [data] = 
    JSON_QUERY( '[' + STUFF(
                            (SELECT ',' + jsonCol FROM #test t3 WHERE t3.id = t2.id FOR XML PATH (''))
                            , 1, 1, '') 
                + ']') 
    FROM #test t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
FROM #test t1
```

Output would be:

```
id  json
1   {"data":[{ "make": "ford" },{ "make": "mazda" }]}
2   {"data":[{ "color": "black" }]}
```